# Is it possible to execute a function in a reusable child component depending on which parent component it is in?

Tags: angular

I have a reusable `ChildComponent` that contains a select with options. I use this component in multiple parent components. I want to execute different functions in the child component depending on the parent where the `(change)` happens. So if a change happens in for example `ParentComponent1` I want to execute the `parent1_function()`. If the change happens in `ParentComponent2` I want to execute the `parent2_function()`. Is this possible with angular and if not what would be clean solution without having to rewrite the select in each parent component

Comment: If the child has to react on the parent's event, and then emit an event to trigger a parent function, then by transitivity, you only need the parent because the child is rendered useless. Please explain your issue more carefully !

Answer (score 1):

So you want to execute a special function in your childComponent if you use a special parent?

Like parent1 use function1 in childComponent. parent2 use function2 in childComponent.

function1 and function2 are using function3 in childComponent. Something like that?

Then I would use callback functions.

parent1.component.ts:

```
  function1(items: any) {
    // do something
  }
```

parent1.component.html

```
<app-child [parentFunction1]="function1"></app-child>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() public parentFunction1: Function;

ngOnInit(){
     this.parentFunction1(this.getItems());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parent component name as `@Input`

Parent HTML:

```
<app-child [parent]="'parent1'"></app-child>
```

Child TS:

`@Input() parent: string`

Child HTML:

`(change) = "parent == 'parent1'?parent1_function():parent2_function()"`

Comment: This is terrible practice because it tightly couples the parent and the child. This means the child is forced to have a specified parent and can't be reused properly.

Comment: Yes.. I understand, but that is the requirement. This shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary

Comment: This isn't the requirement, this is a bad implementation to an awkwardly asked question. If you can implement that, then you can implement an `@Output` in the child to achieve the exact same process you have described here.

Answer (score 0):

With Maryannah comment,

In Parent Component,

`<app-child [options]="data-options" (value_change)="parent_function(value)"></app-child>`

In child.component.ts

`@Output() value_change = new EventEmitter();
..
//other logics
..
onValueChange() {
   value_change.emit(selected_value)
}`